Copying source file from a source generator into the compilation with RegisterPostInitializationOutput
I am authoring an incremental source generator which uses a marker attribute to control the source generation, which is configured via an enum parameter passed to the attribute's constructor, such as:
// user-code
[MarkerAttribute(ConfigFlags.Option1 | ConfigFlags.Option2)]
public class MyClass { }

My generator is then reading the configuration flags from the attribute constructor, where the value is converted back into an enum. The generator definition and the user-code definition for ConfigFlags should be identical.
I am adding the definition of ConfigFlags to the compilation using RegisterPostInitializationOutput, which means that I cannot rely on AdditionalTextsProvider.
I can use reflection to read each enum member from the generator's definition:
(ConfigFlags[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConfigFlags));

And then I can use a StringBuilder to produce the source text without relying on the transform pipeline. This prevents me from having to update the enum source in two files if configuration options are added/removed/renamed.
The problem with this approach is that I cannot add inline XML documentation to the generator's definition of ConfigFlags:
[Flags]
internal enum ConfigFlags
{
    /// <summary>Option 1</summary>
    Option1,
    /// <summary>Option 2</summary>
    Option2
}

The XML documentation will not be reflected in the user-code definition of ConfigFlags, and there is no way to read this via reflection. The XML documentation can be configured in the project settings (of the generator project, not the consuming project) to be output as an XML file on disk, but analyzers (including generators) are not allowed to use file I/O.
What I would like to do is this:
var sb = new StringBuilder("// <auto-generated>").AppendLine();
do
{
    var path = Path.Combine
    (
        Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(ConfigFlags).Assembly.Location),
        "../../../ConfigFlags.cs"
    );
    try
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(path);
        _ = sb.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
        break;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) { }
} while (true);
return sb.ToString();

The reason for the loop is that in practice (when I implemented this), typeof(ConfigFlags).Assembly.Location was sometimes returning a temporary folder, but simply looping and trying again would give me access to the actual project folder.
This works, but it merely circumnavigates the rule against file I/O operations.
I welcome suggestions on an approach to copy the source file contents (think File.ReadAllText()) from the generator project into the user-code compilation with RegisterPostInitializationOutput that doesn't rely on file I/O.

"additional files" are available to source generators without violating the File IO rules - is that an option? i.e. mark the things you're interested in as "additional files"

AdditionalTextsProvider is part of the transform pipeline and provides an IncrementalValueProvider/IncrementalValuesProvider. That can't be consumed through RegisterPostInitializationOutput.

New answer
Through some trial and error, I realized that I can add the following lines to the source generator's .csproj file by hand:
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="ConfigFlags.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

If I change the build action in the properties pane, then this will exclude the file as a "Compile" action, but modifying the project file by hand lets me include the source file as both a source file for compilation and as an embedded resource.
From there, I am able to do the following:
var assembly = typeof(ConfigFlags).Assembly;
var resourcePath = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
    .Where(x => x.EndsWith($"{nameof(ConfigFlags)}.cs"))
    .Single();
using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
var sb = new StringBuilder("// <auto-generated>").AppendLine();
ConfigFlags_SourceText = sb.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd()).ToString();

Where ConfigFlags_SourceText is a static readonly string field. The source text gets updated on build, but this update not a part of the source generator's pipeline at all.
Now I can duplicate the source file from the source generator project into the generated user code, without having to duplicate changes or keep the XML documentation separate from the definitions.
Old answer
Because the approach in the question relies on file I/O, instead I am choosing to resort to creating the user-code enum definition via reflection (as mentioned in the question). I will add the XML documentation on-the-fly to the user-code definition, and simply omit the documentation from the generator definition.
This does unfortunately separate the XML documentation from the enum members that are being documented, but it also means I won't be forced to duplicate any changes in the members or documentation.

In addition to the other considerations I mentioned, the I/O approach I mentioned in the question would also fail if the generator was published as a NuGet package (which I intend to do) rather than being an uncompiled source project in the solution. Perhaps if there were a way to inject the enum definition into the source generator project itself, but source generators can't have dependencies on each other, so I'm not sure that's feasible either.
